# No Google App ID or Google Services file provided while migrating to firebase from Fabric

Tags: swift, firebase

As Firebase is no longer supporting the Fabric I headed over to [migration link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios&authuser=0#firebase-crashlytics-sdk) & followed the steps.

1) changed the podfile to

```swift
# Add the pod for Firebase Crashlytics
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

# Recommended: Add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

2) Then I changed the run script to

```swift
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols"
```

When I try to run the application it gives the below error

```swift
Running upload-symbols in Build Phase mode
Validating build environment for Crashlytics...
Validation succeeded. Exiting because upload-symbols was run in validation mode
[31merror: No Google App ID or Google Services file provided[0m
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

`GoogleService-Info.plist` is there in the root directory when `Info.plist` file is there. It's even checked in the Target Membership.

Why am I getting the above error? 
Please help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by modifying the run script to

```swift
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

To see crash report in firebase do below steps

1. Download the appDsyms from appStore.
2. Run below script in terminal by putting the correct path.

```swift
${path to project}/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp ${path to project}/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ${path to Dsym file}/appDsyms.zip
```

Comment: any luck , did you find ur crash on firebase dashboard

Comment: the run script do we write exactly what you posted or the actual path   as the actual path will change with every archive .

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale I'm facing the same issue, and tried to use your solution, but I got another error saying "-gsp command  not found". Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @LuthfiRahman did you put script in run script? In terminal it gives that error

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale do we have to cope the same in the run script as you have pasted above.

Comment: Yep you should @iMinion

Comment: @iMinion you need not change the path directory as it's been handled by the xcode macros.

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale how  are you getting the crashes on fireBase? after adding the runscript in app  but I don't see crashes on firebase and dsym files are still not uploading .

Comment: @iMinion for that you need to upload the `Xcode Debugging Symbols` file from the iTunes connect to firebase portal then only it shows the crash reports.

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale could you please add a SS on where in FireBase portal we have to do that.

Comment: @iMinion You have to `appDsyms` in firebase using terminal only.

Comment: @AnirudhaMahale that is a manual process which is to be done with every build release, I thought some direct way would be there

Comment: For debug enabled; add -d before -p

Answer (score 1):

Hope if this help some one

I faced this issue in React-Native App, when manually copy-pasted GoogleService-Info.plist in iOS directory, I tried above all solutions but could not fix, due to xCode reference **linking** I added GoogleService-Info.plist files via **File -> Add files to project** or + icon, clean and build again - issue resolved.

make sure you select app and copy if needed checkbox

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue because of typing error. I was wrongly typing "gps" instead of "gsp".